# Sending mail with Gmail OAuth2 C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the AccessToken as a string, I would like to ask if exist any free library to send OAuth2 email using string accesstoken. Not Credential Object.

Comment: I know mailkit but i need to supply only string accesstoken

Comment: Google API Client for Net.  See : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2